# TypeError Prepend is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing this weird issue on Firefox where my code gives me an error:

> TypeError: keyboard.$keyboard.prepend is not a function

The code works fine on Chrome. Following is what was earlier -

```
initialize: function(options) {             
    KText = options.KText;
    KBID = '#' + KText.id +'_keyboard'; 
    $(KText).keyboard({                         
    layout : this.KeyBoardLayout,
    display : $.keyboard.display1,
      visible: function(e, keyboard, el) {                         
        keyboard.$keyboard.prepend("<h2 id='dragKB'></h2>");
        $( "#dragKB" ).draggable({
        target : '#' + KText.id +'_keyboard'
        }); 
    }
```

});

I tried doing this, but no success:

```
visible: function(e, keyboard, el) { 
     var btn = keyboard.$keyboard;
     btn.prepend("<h2 id='dragKB'></h2>");
     $( "#dragKB" ).draggable({
     target : '#' + KText.id +'_keyboard'
     });        
}
```

Any pointers? How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: `$keyboard` doesn't have the method `prepend`, most likely because it's empty

Comment: Any workarounds for this @timenomad ?

Comment: can you show a little more of your code? some html, and where do you use the visible function?

Comment: where did you call the function `visible`

Comment: i called it inside of initialize function

Comment: @KumardevPathak is this occurs also in chrome? or only firefox

Comment: Issue comes only on firefox

Comment: can you `console.log(keyboard);` I want to know whats inside it

Comment: Nothing gets printed in console log

Comment: Although when i do an alert , it opens up on chrome displaying 'object object'

Comment: @KumardevPathak really? it display nothing but show 'object object' when alert?

Comment: Yup , i tried that again and same thing . I don't know what to do as it looks like a very browser specific issue .

Comment: can you show me it's `keyboard` value in chrome?

Comment: $.keyboard {version: "1.25.25", $el: jQuery.fn.init[1], el: textarea#txtTextElement.js-ev-original.ui-keyboard-input.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui-keyboard…, keyBtn: jQuery.fn.init[1], settings: Object…}

Comment: i can see the same value now in firefox too suddenly . But the issue is still there